# Azure API Management - Availability Tests - How to get the HealthCheck url of APIM

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-api-management

I'm working on creating the Availability Tests (a feature of App Insights) to monitor the availability of the API Management Service.

My initial question was "How to get the health check URL of the APIM instance?". After some research, I came to know that the availability tests is created automatically when you select the "Add availability Monitor" checkbox while linking the **Application Insights** to API Management as shown below.

[image]

When I go and check the URL that is used in the Availability Tests, below is what it is.

[image]

The URL has the APIM endpoint and then the "status-0123456789abcdef" segment. What is this segment? I don't this endpoint anywhere in the APIM instance.

Could someone shed some light on whether we can use this safely to create the Availability Tests?

Thanks in advance

Thanks,
Praveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway#step-6) talks about this particular path as a default health endpoint.

It should be safe to use it for your purposes.

[image]